# Java spring boot AuthenticationManager injection faild

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

I am trying to implement the JWT authentication found here. [here](https://medium.com/@xoor/jwt-authentication-service-44658409e12c)
While running I got the following error:

> Field authenticationManager in controllers.SecurityController required
>   a bean of type
>   'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager'
>   that could not be found.
>
> Field authenticationManager in controllers.SecurityController required
>   a bean of type
>   'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager'
>   that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' in
>   your configuration.

Here is my controller:

package controllers;

```
import common.ServiceObjectResponse;
import entity.UserEntity;
import enums.Role;
import exception.CustomException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import request.LoginRequest;
import request.RegisterRequest;
import security.JwtTokenProvider;

import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import services.IUserService;


import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@Api(tags = "diak", value = "SecurityService")
public class SecurityController
{
    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private IUserService _userService;

    @ApiOperation(value = "login", nickname = "login", tags = "login")
    @PostMapping("/api/login")
    @ResponseBody
    public String Login(@RequestBody @Valid LoginRequest data) throws Exception
    {
        ServiceObjectResponse<UserEntity> request = _userService.findByCredentials(data.Email, data.Jelszo);

        if(!request.getIsSuccess())
        {
            throw new Exception(request.getMessage());
        }
        else if(request.getIsSuccess() && request.getObject() == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("No user found with given credantials!");
        }

        UserEntity user = request.getObject();

        try
        {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationData = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(data.Email, data.Jelszo);
            authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationData);

            List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
            roles.add(enums.Role.valueOf(user.Role));

            return jwtTokenProvider.createToken(user.UniqID, roles);
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException e)
        {
            throw new CustomException("Invalid username/password supplied", HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
        }
    }

   return jwtTokenProvider.createToken(user.UniqID, roles);
    }
}
```

Am not good with java. If anyone can help.

thnx

Comment: The exception says it all: you have no Spring bean `org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager` defined in your application. Please provide the relevant part of your code (dependencies and spring configuration)

Comment: please follow the steps written in this article https://medium.com/@dassum/securing-spring-boot-rest-api-with-json-web-token-and-jdbc-token-store-67558a7d6c29

Comment: I just realized that the code on github has error. Missing the part in WebSecurityConfig with the AuthenticationManager part.